# NullPointerException at com.firebase.ui.auth.core.FirebaseLoginBaseActivity.onStart(FirebaseLoginBaseActivity.java:118)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to show Google Login Option using [FirebaseUI-Android library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) (Version 0.3.0), I followed the exact same steps mentioned on the Github repository. But app is crashing right after i start the app.

Exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at 
com.firebase.ui.auth.core.FirebaseLoginBaseActivity.onStart(FirebaseLoginBaseActivity.java:118)
    at com.shajeelafzal.LoginActivity.onStart(LoginActivity.java:27)
```

The line # 27 is calling the `super.onStart()`

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart(); // Line # 27
    setEnabledAuthProvider(SocialProvider.google);
}
```

I am calling `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);` in the `onCreate` of `Application` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the wonderful things about FirebaseUI is that it's an open-source project, so you can check what the lines in the stack trace refer to. In this case, [line 118 of `FirebaseLoginBaseActivity`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/0.3.0/library/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/core/FirebaseLoginBaseActivity.java#L118) is:

```
getFirebaseRef().addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
```

So it looks like you're not implementing `getFirebaseRef()` in `com.shajeelafzal.LoginActivity` or at least are returning null when `onStart()` is executed.

The usual implementation is something like:

```
public class LoginActivity extends FirebaseLoginBaseActivity {
    Firebase mFirebaseRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

      mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(...);

      ...
    }

    @Override
    protected Firebase getFirebaseRef() {
       return mFirebaseRef;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try to explore the code next time. I have separate minor question. Instead of showing the Auth options in a Dialog can show it in the layout? Does library provide any convenient way to do so? Otherwise i think i will have to manually do that.

Comment: App is crashing when i click on the Login Button. `NullPointerException at com.firebase.ui.auth.google.GoogleAuthProvider.login(GoogleAuthProvider.java:119) at com.firebase.ui.auth.core.FirebaseLoginDialog$2.onClick(FirebaseLoginDialog.java:181)`, Trying to Understand the code of `FirebaseLoginDialog`

Comment: A note on the above crash: In the onStart method i am enabling auth provider as: `setEnabledAuthProvider(SocialProvider.google);`, I used `SocialProvider.google` because i was not able to import `AuthProviderType.GOOGLE`

Comment: It looks like the source code in `core` is updated 3 days ago https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/core i am going to dowload the of 0.3.1 and include it in the project.

Comment: I included the 0.3.1 library version as Mobile dependency and I am getting this error after including the module as dependency. Error:Execution failed for task ':library:processReleaseGoogleServices'. > No matching client found for package name 'com.firebase.ui'